# Reload TableView More Than Once Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, timer

I am trying to reload a tableview in swift more than once. As shown in the code below, initially, after 0.5 seconds, the tableview "reloads" and all of the elements for the tableview from Firebase are loaded; however, after 5.0 seconds, when runTimer() is called, the tableview doesn't reload. In essence, I am trying to "reload" the data everytime something is updated in Firebase but nothing seems to work. Any help in resolving this is appreciated as I have looked all over SO and haven't had any luck.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            checkFireBase()

            tableViewResults.delegate = self
            tableViewResults.dataSource = self

            let nibName = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
            tableViewResults.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")

            txtsearchBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchRecords(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

                self.tableViewResults.reloadData()

            }

           runTimer()
        }

   func runTimer(){
        self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 5.0, repeats: true, block: { (Timer) in
            self.vehicleArray.removeAll()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.checkFireBase()

            }
        })

        RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        self.tableViewResults.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: How do you know the data is not reloaded. You seem to be trying to reload t every 5 seconds, but if the data does. Or change it will just look the same.

Comment: @Chris I can see that it changed by putting in a print statement and I see that it is getting the updated values from firebase but the tableview isn't reloading and displaying the correct/updated information

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update

Comment: I have an idea, put the reload tableView call at the end of your `checkFirebase()` method (or inside the timer’s block). Currently the reload code gets called once when `runTimer()` is called, but is not called by the timer’s code block.

Comment: @rengineer you don't need the timer here, you should use the realtime listeners of firebase, see my answer below

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi That’s a good point - I’m not familiar with Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the timer here you can use the listeners provided by firebase, that are automatically called when data is updated in the Firebase realtime database. see this link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

Comment: feels great to help somene  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have clarified that your `checkFirebase()` method is updating your data. However the `self.tableViewResults.reloadData()` only gets called once (when `runTimer()` is called) and is not called by the timer’s code block.

Either put `self.tableViewResults.reloadData()` inside your `checkFirebase()` method or inside the timer’s block. This will reload the tableView each time the timer is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The timer will execute the code which is present in the completion handler or completion block.

> So your table update call `self.tableViewResults.reloadData()`
>   in the `runTimer()` function call will be executed only when you call
>   the function. **To update the table you need to reload the table when
>   you update your data source.**

Try the following

```
func runTimer(){
        self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 5.0, repeats: true, block: { (Timer) in
            self.vehicleArray.removeAll()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.checkFireBase()

            }
        })

        RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        self.tableViewResults.reloadData()

    }

    func checkFireBase(){
        //Fetch the latest data and update the data Source of your Table view
         self.tableViewResults.reloadData()
    }
```